# XSLT: How to represent OR in a "match" attribute?

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to perform a series of operations on elements that matched the name "A" or "B". I'm thinking of something like this below, but it doesn't work.

```
<xsl:template match= " 'A' or 'B'" >
     <!-- whatever I want to do here -->
</xsl:template>
```

Couldn't find the appropriate XSLT language reference for it. Please help! Thanks!!

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14057312/2047725

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Try this:

```
<xsl:template match= "A | B" >
```

[See this page for details.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256074(VS.85).aspx)

Answer (score 31):

Generally `A | B` is the right way to do this.  But the pipe character is basically a union of two complete XPath expressions.  It can be annoying to use it in a case like this:

```
/red/yellow/blue/green/gold | red/orange/blue/green/gold
```

since you're repeating the entirety of the expression except for the one small piece of it's that changing.

In cases like this, it often makes sense to use a predicate and the `name()` function instead:

```
/red/*[name() = 'yellow' or name()='orange']/blue/green/gold
```

This technique gives you access to a much broader range of logical operations.  It's also (conceivably) faster, as the XPath navigator only has to traverse the nodes it's testing once.

Comment: Best and most complete answer to me

Answer (score 12):

I think it's more convenient to use this XPath

```
/red/(yellow | orange)/blue/green/gold
```

rather than

```
/red/*[name() = 'yellow' or name()='orange']/blue/green/gold
```

Comment: This doesn't work in a `match` attribute for `template`. It's valid XPATH but not a valid pattern.

Answer (score 8):

> `<xsl:template match= " 'A' or 'B'" >`

**There are a few problems with this match pattern**:

1. A template matches **nodes**, not strings. Therefore, the names of the elements to be matched should not be specified as quoted strings.
2. The **[XPath operator "or"](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath#NT-OrExpr)** acts on two boolean values, not on nodes. What is necessary here is [**another XPath operator -- the *union* operator "|"**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath#node-sets).

Taking into account the above, one will correctly specify the template rule as:

```
<xsl:template match= "A | B" >
     <!-- whatever I want to do here -->
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1):

The below information was gleaned from: http://www.cafeconleche.org/books/bible2/chapters/ch17.html#d1e2090

I will paraphrase, please search for the text "Using the or operator |" in that document.

The syntax is:

```
<xsl:template match="A|B">
   <!-- Do your stuff> -->
</xsl:template>
```