# How to match this OR that in an xsl template?

Tags: xslt

In my Sharepoint `fldtypes_custom.xsl` file, I have this code, which works perfectly.  However, I want to use the same code on three or four similar fields.

Is there a way I can match fields named `status1` OR `status2`, OR `status3` in the same template?  Right now I have to have three copies of this block of code where the only difference is the `fieldref` name.  I would like to consolodate the code.

```
<xsl:template match="FieldRef[@Name='status1']" mode="body">
    <xsl:param name="thisNode" select="."/>
    <xsl:variable name="currentValue" select="$thisNode/@status1" />
    <xsl:variable name="statusRating1">(1)</xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="statusRating2">(2)</xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="statusRating3">(3)</xsl:variable>

    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains($currentValue, $statusRating1)">
            <span class="statusRatingX statusRating1"></span>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="contains($currentValue, $statusRating2)">
            <span class="statusRatingX statusRating2"></span>
        </xsl:when> 
        <xsl:when test="contains($currentValue, $statusRating3)">
            <span class="statusRatingX statusRating3"></span>
        </xsl:when> 
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <span class="statusRatingN"></span>
        </xsl:otherwise>                    
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/q/616427/2047725

Comment: Just wanted to link the two for the benefit of future readers

Comment: Ah, thanks then.  I approve heartily of linking questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way I can match fields named status1 OR status2, OR status3
>   in the same template?

**Use**:

```
<xsl:template match="status1 | status2 | status3">
  <!-- Your processing here -->
</xsl:template>
```

**However**, I see from the provided code, that the strings `"status1"`, `"status2"` and `"status3"` aren't element names -- they are just possible values of the `Name` attribute of the `FieldRef` element.

**In this case, your template could be**:

```
<xsl:template match="FieldRef
     [@Name = 'status1' or @Name = 'status2' or @Name = 'status3']">
  <!-- Your processing here -->
</xsl:template>
```

**In case there are many possible values for the `Name` attribute, one can use the following abbreviation**:

```
<xsl:template match="FieldRef
     [contains('|status1|status2|staus3|', concat('|',@Name, '|'))]">
  <!-- Your processing here -->
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks, Dimitre.  That's exactly what I was looking for.  Now, in the `test` code, I am also getting the value of the field into a variable with something like this: `<xsl:variable name="currentValue" select="$thisNode/@status1" />`  Is there a way to use a wildcard there to get whatever the value might be based on the match of the 'fieldref'?

Comment: @BGM, If it is guaranteed that the element contained in `$thisNode` has only one attribute whose hame starts with the string `"status"` then do: `$thisNode/@*[starts-with(name(), 'status')]` . The current question has been completely answered, so please, *accept* it and ask any new question as ... a new question.

Comment: Sorry - no need to chide me.  I was going to mark it anyway, whether you added another comment or not because you did answer it.

Comment: @BGM, You are welcome. I wasn't chiding, but it is true that comments are a poor format for sharing code. I would be glad to answer your next question.

Comment: Thanks, Dimitre.  You are right.  No hard feelings.  I'll post my question.

Comment: Dimitre, I am trying to match all columns with ""phone" in the `@Name` with a single xsl template.  I tried the `contains` code, but it only matches if it is an exact match.  What about a partial match?  Maybe this should be a different question.

Comment: Ah, here is my new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26977990/xsl-partial-match-on-name