# Matching two Fields in XSLT and Getting Current Value

Tags: xslt

In my XSLT, I have this function, which successfully matches either/or/and two columns.  The `FieldRef` matches perfectly.

My problem is that `$currentValue` never seems to be equal to what I am testing (what I am testing seems to be a blank string).

Where am I going wrong here?

```
<!-- Convert the Fields into a status icons    -->
<xsl:template match="FieldRef[@Name='YesNo']|FieldRef[@Name='TrueFalse']" mode="body">
    <xsl:param name="thisNode" select="." />
    <xsl:variable name="currentValue" select="$thisNode/@*[name()=current()/@Name]" />

    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$currentValue='Yes'">
            <span class="yesno yes"><xsl:value-of select="$currentValue" /></span>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$currentValue='No'">
            <span class="yesno no"><xsl:value-of select="$currentValue" /></span>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$currentValue='True'">
            <span class="yesno yes"><xsl:value-of select="$currentValue" /></span>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$currentValue='False'">
            <span class="yesno no"><xsl:value-of select="$currentValue" /></span>
        </xsl:when>     
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <span class="yesnoN"><xsl:value-of select="$currentValue" /></span>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>

</xsl:template>
```

One thing I do know is that if I do

```
<xsl:variable name="thisName" select="./@Name" /> select="./@Name" />
```

then it *will* try to match using the name of the field itself (instead of its value).

What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, after hours and hours, here it is:

These two lines are the keys:

```
<xsl:param name="thisNode" select="."/>
<xsl:variable name="currentValue" select="$thisNode/@*[name()=current()/@Name]" />
```

Here is the entire function, which reads two different columns and applies the values to either one:

```
<xsl:template match="FieldRef[@Name='YesNo1']|FieldRef[@Name='YesNo2']" mode="body">
    <xsl:param name="thisNode" select="."/>

    <xsl:variable name="currentValue" select="$thisNode/@*[name()=current()/@Name]" />
    <xsl:variable name="yesvalue">Yes</xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="novalue">No</xsl:variable>

    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains($currentValue, $yesvalue)">
            <span class="yesno yes"><xsl:value-of select="$currentValue" /></span>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="contains($currentValue, $novalue)">
            <span class="yesno no"><xsl:value-of select="$currentValue" /></span>
        </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
            <span class="yesnoN"><xsl:value-of select="$currentValue" /></span>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>

</xsl:template>
```

*There are [some other examples of matching on multiple match fields here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14057312/how-to-match-this-or-that-in-an-xsl-template?rq=1).*